# Получение уникального ID Android

Tags: java, c#, android, unity3d

Создаю в игре функцию сохранения некоторых игровых данных пользователя, чтобы в случае переустановки приложения можно было эти данные восстановить. В связи с чем возник вопрос: как получить такой уникальный ID, чтобы при переустановке игры можно было точно сопоставить данные из БД для данного пользователя (естественно, при условии, что устройство то же), не прибегая к использованию опасных и запрашиваемых разрешений? Поделитесь, кто как решает данный вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972404/10138734

Comment: @Akina, `READ_PHONE_STATE` является `Dangerous permissions`

Comment: A `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` - является? если нет (а https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview считает его PROTECTION_NORMAL) - возьмите MAC-адрес WiFi-адаптера, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11705949/10138734. Хотя как по мне, сгенерить что-нибудь круто-рандомное, какой-нить хэш на полкило (или сколько там по максимуму в один пакет влезает у вайфая с учётом всех протоколов?), оттолкнувшись от текущего времени, да сохранить.

Comment: @Akina, я может в посте не совсем понятно описал, но этот ID должен быть всегда одинаковый, т.е, если пользователь переустановил игру, игра должна сгенерить этот ID и он должен быть таким же, как и ранее. Ваш совет имеет силу, только если надо единожды сгенерить уникальный ID, в другое время точно такой же не получится (если делать привязку ко времени). По поводу MAC Wi-Fi тоже думал, но когда гуглил видел инфу, что мак может не прочитаться, если модуль Wi-Fi выключен.

Comment: *видел инфу, что мак может не прочитаться, если модуль Wi-Fi выключен* Игра, как я понимаю, онлайновая, да и в комментарии к [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009032/229437) Вы пишете, что разрешение INTERNET имеется - а потому ничто не мешает отложить генерацию до первого запуска игры, когда подключение, и, соответственно, МАС-адрес, есть.

Comment: Правда, тут есть две тонкости. Во-первых, МАС можно и изменить. Во-вторых, подключить смартфон к Инету можно и через Bluetooth, и через USB.

Comment: @Akina, _подключить смартфон к Инету можно и через Bluetooth, и через USB_, верно заметили, к ним же и мобильный интернет.

Answer (score 1):

Начну с конца.

Если будете хранить ту же БД на устройстве, то разрешения на файловую систему Вам всё равно потребуются. Без них Вам будут доступны только те папки, до которых можно достучаться через контекст. А, они обычно удаляются автоматически вместе с приложением.

Если планируете выгружать данные на сервер, Вам понадобится разрешение `INTERNET`.

Так что без разрешений никак.

Что касается ID. В зависимости от задачи его можно гененировать различными способами (GUID, CUID, etc...) или использовать идентификаторы связанные с аппаратной частью телефона (тот же [IMEI и пр.](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/27109/)).

Comment: БД удаленно, `INTERNET` есть

Comment: Ну так генерируйте какой-нибудь id, например по логину и паролю, и по нему выгружайте нужные данные на устройство.

Answer (score 0):

Решил использовать метод получения уникального ID, который используется для обозначения устройства как тестового, при билде запроса в AdMob. Может еще как-то модифицирую его с данными о железе.

Вызов `generateDeviceUniqueIdentifier(false);`

```
static string generateDeviceUniqueIdentifier(bool oldBehavior) {
    string id = "";
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject activity = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaClass contextClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Context");
    string TELEPHONY_SERVICE = contextClass.GetStatic<string>("TELEPHONY_SERVICE");
    AndroidJavaObject telephonyService = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    bool noPermission = false;
    try {
        id = telephonyService.Call<string>("getDeviceId");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        noPermission = true;
    }
    if(id == null)
        id = "";
    if((noPermission && !oldBehavior) || (!noPermission && id == "" && oldBehavior)) {
        AndroidJavaClass settingsSecure = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings$Secure");
        string ANDROID_ID = settingsSecure.GetStatic<string>("ANDROID_ID");
        AndroidJavaObject contentResolver = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver");
        id = settingsSecure.CallStatic<string>("getString", contentResolver, ANDROID_ID);
        if(id == null)
            id = "";
    }
    if(id == "") {
        string mac = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
        try {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/sys/class/net/wlan0/address");
            mac = reader.ReadLine();
            reader.Close();
        } catch(Exception e) { }
        id = mac.Replace(":", "");
    }
    return getMd5Hash(id);
}

static string getMd5Hash(string input) {
    if(input == "")
        return "";
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Еще как вариант можно использовать только `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID`.

```
public static string Retrieve(){
    AndroidJavaClass clsUnity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject objActivity = clsUnity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject objResolver = objActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver");
    AndroidJavaClass clsSecure = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings$Secure");
    string ANDROID_ID = clsSecure.GetStatic<string>("ANDROID_ID");
    string androidId = clsSecure.CallStatic<string>("getString", objResolver, ANDROID_ID);
    return androidId;
}
```